# why is (a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple') happening?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

*I'm a newbie in python so I gotta apologize beforehand if the question's silly!*

**The Error is:**

> a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'

If I understood the documentations correctly, `socket.bind()` and `socket.connect()` require a tuple of the intended IP address and port, if the first index is an empty string, so we're listening for any host on the specific port we use in the second index of the tuple

**The code is:**

```
def SomeFunction(SomeArguments):
     s = socket.socket(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
     connection_tuple = (str(master_ip), int(master_port))
     s.bind(connection_tuple)
     s.listen(5)
     print (">>> RTU is Listening for {}, {}...".format(master_ip, master_port))
     c, addr = s.accept()
     print ('>>> Got connection from ', addr)
     while True:
          try:
               msg = c.recv(2048)
               print (">> Packet Received : {}".format(msg))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for x in range(len(dnpMaster_ip)):
        Thread(target=dnp_request_handler, args=(dnpSlave_id, dnpMaster_ip[x], dnpMaster_id[x], dnp_port[x])).start()
```

though when I use `s.bind(('', 20000))` the code works fine, but when i use any kind of variable or a str IP address, I get the error.
any help would be appreciated. tnx

Comment: @stovfl do u mean like this: `s.bind(**connection_tuple)`, cuz it shows the error `bind() argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple`. If you could send me a link to read about it or a piece of code to test I'd appreciate it, tnx

Comment: You claim, ***use s.bind(('', 20000)) the code works fine***, i couldn't confirm that. See [reply.it](https://repl.it/repls/DapperSnoopyOrders). Your problem are your [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html?highlight=socket%20bind#socket-families), you create a `AF_UNIX` but you want to use the `AF_INET` binding, which requires tuple. First, confirm that you really want a `AF_UNIX` socket!